# identificar punto decimal y tomar solo 3 decimales

Tags: javascript, decimal

Estoy mandado un calculo de numero que en ciertos casos puede contener punto decimal y mas de 3 decimales, ejemplo: `43.2345667428`

Estoy buscando saber como identificar estos casos y tomar solo 3 decimales despues del punto, he intentado esto, pero aun no logro resolverlo.

```
var resultado = Reporte[0].Consumo; //aqui viene el dato del consumo que puede ser o no decimal

if (resultado % 1 == 0) {
            alert ("Es un numero entero");

} else {
            alert ("Es un numero decimal");

}

document.getElementById("Consumo").value = resultado; //mandar informacion a pantalla
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu lógica funciona bien para saber si un número es decimal o no, así que sólo te falta reducirle los decimales después del punto, que se puede hacer usando el método toFixed()

```js
var resultado = Reporte[0].Consumo; //aqui viene el dato del consumo que puede ser o no decimal

if (resultado % 1 == 0) {
            alert ("Es un numero entero");

} else {
            alert ("Es un numero decimal");
        resultado = Number(resultado.toFixed(3))
}

document.getElementById("Consumo").value = resultado; //mandar informacion a pantalla
```

Comment: Debería ser `resultado = Number(resultado).toFixed(3)`... porque si `Consumo` es un string como "3.24" no va a funcionar y sacara error: `toFixed is not a function`. Poniendo el toFixed despues del number funcionará en ambos casos

Comment: Estoy aplicando el Number de esa forma porque dijo que iba a utilizar el resultado para hacer algunas operaciones, y supongo que si ese es el caso, consumo también va a entrar como número, la lógica no cambia para nada, lo único que cambiaría sería el cómo juegue con los tipos de las variables según lo vaya a utilizar él

Answer (score 0):

crea una funcion que multiplique al valor por el numero 10(1 decima),100(2 decima),1000(3 decimales) dependiendo el numero de decimales que desees revisar o colocar, y realiza la comprobacion diviendo entre 1 (% 1 == 0), si es cero, siginifica que es el decimal consultado, haz un Math.floor(del resultado) y luego una funcion que retorne el valor dividiendo al mismo valor por el que multiplicaste

te dejo el codigo

```js
var resultado1 = 123.456789
var resultado2 = 123.456



function funRevision(){
console.log('revisando')

var valorTipoNumero = Number( document.getElementById("numeroIngresado").value )
var cantDecimales = Number( document.getElementById("seleccionDecimales").value )
console.log(valorTipoNumero)
console.log(cantDecimales)

if ( this.multiplicar(valorTipoNumero,cantDecimales) % 1 == 0) {
            console.log ("valor es un numero de " + cantDecimales +  " decimales o menos");

} else {
            console.log ("valor de mas de " + cantDecimales +  " decimales");
}

}


//** en cualquier caso para transformar un numero con decimales deseados *//
            var numero1Nuevo = this.dividir( Math.floor(this.multiplicar(resultado1,3)),3)
            console.log('nuevo ',numero1Nuevo)

function  multiplicar(a,x){
    const largos = [ 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
    var b = a * largos[x]
    return b
  }
function  dividir(a,x){
    const largos = [ 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
    var b = a / largos[x]
    return b
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numeroIngresado" value=123.456>

<select id="seleccionDecimales">
  <option value=1>1</option>  
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3 selected>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>

</select>

<button id='funRevision' type="button" onclick="funRevision()">revisar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

El JavaScript, al recibir un valor, intentará interpretar el tipo de ese valor. Los valores pueden ser interpretarse como números. Si el valor no puede interpretarse como un número, se tratará como una cadena.

Para empezar a resolverlo, comprenda esta parte para evitar problemas con [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

La forma más sencilla de resolverlo sin necesidad de conversión es:

El resultado multiplicado por 1000 causará el desplazamiento de la coma decimal hacia la derecha en 3 posiciones decimales.

Cuando redondees y dividas por 1000, la coma se desplazará hacia la izquierda 3 posiciones decimales y el resultado tendrá 3 posiciones decimales.

```js
var resultado = 43.2345667428;
resultado = resultado * 1000;
resultado = Math.round(resultado);
resultado = resultado / 1000;
console.log(resultado)
```

```js
var resultado = 43.2345667428;
var decimales = resultado.toString().split(".")[1].length;

if (decimales > 3) {
  resultado = Math.round(resultado * 1000) / 1000;
}

console.log(resultado);
```

[`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) : convierte el número resultado en una cadena de caracteres.

[`.split(".")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) : divide la cadena en dos partes, la parte entera y la parte decimal.

[`[1].length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)  : la longitud de la parte decimal.

`if (decimales > 3) {}`  : compara si la parte decimal tiene más de 3 dígitos.